# Proving the complex function $f(n) = n^2 + 2$ is onto

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the question,

For the function:

$$ f: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C} $$
$$ f(n) = n^2 +2 $$
Is $ f $ onto? Justify your answer.

So this was my approach
$$ a+bi = (c+di)^2 +2 $$
$$ a+bi = c^2 -d^2 +2cdi + 2 $$
$$ a = c^2 -d ^2 + 2 $$
$$ b = 2cd $$

At this point, I know I must prove that for any $a$ and $b$ there exists a $c$ and $d$ but I do not know how.

Comment: Are you sure the function is complex? $\mathbf{Z}$ usually refers to the integers.

Comment: For any $z \in \mathbb C$, since $z-2 \in \mathbb C$, $(z-2)^{1/2}$ is also in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @0XLR thank you for pointing that out! Yes it is supposed to be C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you probably meant to write $\mathbf C$ rather than $\mathbf Z$. It is decidedly not onto for $\mathbf Z$, for instance, $-10$ is not in the image. However, it is onto for $\mathbf C$. I think the easiest way to understand this is with the polar form of a complex number.

For $w \in \mathbf C$ we can write $w = r e^{i \theta}$ where $r, \theta \in \mathbb R$ and $r > 0$. $r$ is the magnitude of $w$ and $\theta$ is the angle it makes with the positive real axis. If you're not comfortable with complex exponentials, just define $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$. Now, for $z \in \mathbf C$, write $z - 2 = r e^{i \theta}$. Then $(\sqrt{r} e^{i \theta/2})^2 = re^{i \theta} = z - 2$, so $f(\sqrt{r} e^{i \theta/2}) = z$ so $f$ is onto. Geometrically, $\sqrt{r} e^{i \theta/2}$ is the resulting of square rooting the magnitude and cutting the angle with the positive real axis in half.

Comment: Simply use the fact that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: That's quite a bit more advanced than the proof I gave, but it will of course work.